# Tiny sample JQuery get fail?

Tags: jquery, html, http, text

some days are just like this. Ok, I'm trying to fetch some text using ... well, anything that will work. I thought JQuery might be a good approach, but, for good measure, i'll try XMLHttpRequest, too. Totally silent failure from both. I guess I just don't understand even this tiniest, simplest case. Here it is

If I type the following into the address bar of just about any browser, I get some nice text in a window

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11.txt

Now, I want to write a little html file, on my disk, to do the same thing. Here is my attempt; I've gone over every letter of this file again and again, and checked with several online documents for proper JQuery & XMLHttpRequest syntax, and I cannot see anything wrong at all. But neither approach does anything at all.

Any advice?

Alice?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

  document.write('Alice?')
  $.get(
    'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11.txt', 
    function(data) {
      document.write(data);
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function GetURL()
    {
        document.write('Alice?');
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11.txt';
        request.open('GET', url, false);
        request.send(null);
        document.write(request.responseText);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: so you are attempting do do a get on your local file path without going through the browser (server)?

Comment: What I WANTED to do was write a web application that could pull public-domain texts from various sources around the web -- like gutenberg, but there are others -- and combine them in the app, doing things like computing word counts. JavaScript seemed a natural platform to write such an application, but now I'm stuck. I'll have to write it in Silverlight or Flash or both or god-knows-what. Maybe this is worth a top-level question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Cross-Domain Access problem (violation of Same Origin Policy). Essentially JavaScript refuses to load stuff from other servers (in newer Browsers, IE6 happily loads everything from anyone).

There are some workarounds listed in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg624360.aspx) (Server Side proxy, IFrame, Flash/Silverlight plugin, CORS, JSONP) and another idea is [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX doesn't allow you to access files on a different domain. If, however, you saved the file to your hard drive in the same place as your HTML and then used `11.txt` instead of the URL, it would work.

Comment: I see. Kinda sad, but I get the point. Thanks for the answer!